# Why openjdk-10 is missing in 18.04 PPA where openjdk-11 is available?

Tags: ppa, openjdk

```
$ sudo apt install openj
openjade                 openjdk-11-jre           openjdk-8-doc            openjdk-8-jre-zero
openjdk-11-dbg           openjdk-11-jre-headless  openjdk-8-jdk            openjdk-8-source
openjdk-11-demo          openjdk-11-jre-zero      openjdk-8-jdk-headless   openjfx
openjdk-11-doc           openjdk-11-source        openjdk-8-jre            openjfx-source
openjdk-11-jdk           openjdk-8-dbg            openjdk-8-jre-dcevm      
openjdk-11-jdk-headless  openjdk-8-demo           openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

My question is ubuntu shows openjdk-11 in their ppa, but why it doesn't show openjdk-10, although openjdk-10 is stable release and openjdk-11 is in development.

Comment: You must ask the PPA author why they made their choices. PPAs are not the official, supported Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @user535733 Where can I find the author and how I can ask him?

Comment: Start at launchpad.net.

Comment: @user535733 this screenshot is taken from a fresh ubuntu after installation then why it is not official?

Comment: @user535733 I didn't add any PPA about openjdk.

Comment: You asked about package choices in a PPA - it's right there in the title. Perhaps you have a different question?

Comment: Perhaps the questioner means "the 18.04 repositories" rather than "the 18.04 PPA".